# Underscore debounce with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Suppose I have this event handler:

```
var mousewheel = function (e) { /* blah */ };
```

But, I want to debounce it. So I do this, which works as expected:

```
var mousewheelDebounced = _.debounce(mousewheel, 500);
$(document).on("mousewheel", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mousewheelDebounced(e);
}
```

But *this doesn't work as expected*:

```
$(document).on("mousewheel", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  _.debounce(mousewheel, 500)(e);
}
```

I prefer the compactness of the second form. But no debouncing occurs.

I assume no reference to the `mousewheelDebounced` remains, so the underlying handler is called every time. Is that the reason? How can I clean up this code, if possible?

You can see a **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hygo4oo6/)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each `mousewheel` event (which occurs very often) you create a new version of `debounce` function. This function has no history, and doesn't know that on previous event there was another one created. So it just runs. That's why you should go with the first version.

Comment: That code executes every time, no debouncing occurs.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My fiddle works though: http://jsfiddle.net/hygo4oo6/ Your original comment is true, I think there needs to be a reference somewhere to the debounced function.

Comment: Your version that debounces the entire callback does not `.preventDefault()` all events, though.

Comment: @Bergi It's true, missed that.

Comment: @dfsq Your answer is good except the code, if you remove it I can accept the answer...

Comment: You are right, the code does not correspond the question. I will remove it.