# event.preventDefault is not preventing scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash, debouncing

after implementing the `debounce` function from lodash the function is not longer capable of preventing the user from scrolling on the website.

I tried to outsource the `debounce` part of lodash into another function, but I couldn't get it to work this way.

This is the code:

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', _.debounce(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        var a= document.getElementsByClassName('mouseScrollAnchor');
        if(wd < 0) {
            for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t >= 40) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t < -20) break;
            }
        }

        if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
            });
        }
    }, 500));
```

What I expect from the function to do:
It prevents the user from scrolling normally, instead it should scroll to the next anchor in the list of anchors.

What it does:
It does let the user scroll manually (which should not be allowed) and after .5 seconds it scrolls to the anchor.

Basically it is working like intended, except the `event.preventDefault` part.

**Edit:**
It's working now!
Below you can find the working code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var changeView = function(event){
        var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        var a= document.getElementsByClassName('mouseScrollAnchor');
        if(wd < 0) {
            for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t >= 40) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if(t < -20) break;
            }
        }

        if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
            });
        }
    };

    var mousewheelDebounced = _.debounce(changeView, 25);

    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mousewheelDebounced(event);
    });

    /*...*/

}
```

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237942/debounce-function-means-e-preventdefault-on-mousewheel-no-longer-working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore debounce with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337905/underscore-debounce-with-arguments)

Comment: Issue is when debounce runs, the event is already done

Comment: @mjwills thank you very much! I'll edit the working code into the post.

Comment: Put your working code as the **answer** not in the **question**. It is fine to answer your own question.